# Subgraph Link for Uniswap V2 on BSC?

Tags: contract-development, uniswap, bsc, decentralized-exchange, subgraph

I'm looking for the SubGraph Api endpoint to interact with UniswapV2 on the Binance Smart Chain (BSC). Can anyone provide the specific link or information on how to access it? I appreciate any assistance or pointers to the relevant documentation. Thanks!

Comment: `Can anyone provide the specific link or information on how to access it?` Why do you think there is one?